# Jquery show hide specific amount of ul li

Tags: jquery, events, function

I have a function `webResultTotal` This function is related to a number which can be anything from 0 to a billion. I also have an ul with up to 500 li items. I would like the following to happen on keyup:

if `webResultTotal` is 500 or less, then show the amount of li items related to the number given by `webResultTotal`

if `webResultTotal` is more than 500 show all of the li tems which is 500 in total.

I hope this make sense..I googled for it but found no simple Jquery way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
$('li:gt('+((webResultTotal <500)?webResultTotal:500)+')').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question which I interpret as "don't show more than 500 li" all you would need is:

```
$('li:gt(499)').hide(); /* if there are less than 500 this will fail quietly*/
```

If you are trying to ask for more advanced behavior it is not clear in question

Comment: Hi I will test this later (no time right now..) But do you think that if "webResultTotal" = 347 it will show 347 li items, instead of 499..? I dont see that happening but I could be mistaken.

Comment: that is correct, and the 499 is index which is zero based, so will show 500